# Importing external library into eclipse - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to use the [UnifiedPreference](https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference) library in my app. I've imported the library into my workspace, then added the new project into my existing project by adding it as a library under Properties -> Android. However I'm getting the following errors when I try to build my project which are coming from the UnifiedPreference project:

Console:

```
[2013-04-08 23:06:29 - unified-pref-library] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> PreferenceHeader, unable to find attribute icon
[2013-04-08 23:06:29 - unified-pref-library] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> PreferenceHeader, unable to find attribute title
```

The relevent logcat errors seem to be:

```
PreferenceHeader_title cannot be resolved or is not a field UnifiedPreferenceHelper.java    /unified-pref-library/src/net/saik0/android/unifiedpreference   line 435    Java Problem
PreferenceHeader_title cannot be resolved or is not a field UnifiedPreferenceHelper.java    /unified-pref-library/src/net/saik0/android/unifiedpreference   line 299    Java Problem
```

Have I imported the library incorrectly? I've tried cleaning and building both projects without anything changing.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:

1. On the `Package Explorer`
2. Right click in your `Proyect` > `Properties`
3. Select: `Java Build Path`
4. Select and enable `Android Dependencies`
5. Put on the top in the list
6. Click: `OK`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, seems UnifiedPreference requires a dependency for ActionBarSherlock. Thanks to tttony for putting me on the right track though.